# Run WSL command in non-interactive mode (Fall Creators Update)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Before Fall Creators Update I could run Ubuntu binaries in one-liner via such command:

```
%WinDir%\system32\bash.exe -c "echo 123"
```

But after the update, I can't find how to do the same thing with MarketPlace-installed distro. Is there a way to run such commands in cmd.exe?

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45959560/is-it-possible-to-run-wsl-bash-in-non-interactive-mode

Answer (score 1):

Why can't? Bash.exe and wsl.exe always run your default distro.
Change default distro by wslconfig.exe

Or use ubuntu.exe to run Ubuntu, opensuse.exe to run OpenSUSE.
Open

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

to see all your distro launcher.