# Does there a Windows equivalent exist for "svn ls...." command?

Tags: windows, jenkins, svn

I try to find the windows equivalent of the next linux command:

```
Highest_Tool_Version=`svn ls --username ${CREDENTIAL_NAME} --password ${CREDENTIAL_PW} --non-interactive http://<domain>/Tool/tags | sort -V | tail -n 1`
```

Maybe not needed to tell, but the function is: return one, the last, tag. We use this for checking out files.

At this moment we have Jenkins running on a Linux master. But now we also have a Jenkins Windows Master, so I need this command for a windows environment.

With regards,

Nico

Answer (score 0):

You are not looking for a Windows equivalent of `svn ls`. `svn list` is a Subversion client command (svn.exe) and you need to install svn.exe on your Windows machine.

What you are looking for is:

- using [Windows Batch variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552812/defining-and-using-a-variable-in-batch-file) to replace `${CREDENTIAL_NAME}` and `${CREDENTIAL_PW}`,
- using Windows [`sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sort) command,
- using [Windows alternative to `tail` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command).

BTW, you could also use [Bash on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), but AFAIK [it does not work in non-interactive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45959560/761095).